# Display a picture saved in HTML into a Vue.js page

Tags: javascript, python, html, vue.js

I am currently trying to display a local picture saved in HTML into my Vue.js page.
I have tried to load the content of the HTML file into a variable using the following lines:

```
computed: {
    compiledHtml: function() {
      return this.asset;
    }
      const path = 'http://localhost:5000/load_results'
      axios
        .get(path)
        .then((res) => {
          this.asset = res.data
        })
```

Then I have tried to display it using `v-html`:
`<div v-html="compiledHtml"></div>`

It actually works with a simple HTML file which contains a few lines, for example:
`<h1> test load HTML file </h1>`

However, my picture size is 3.5Mb and is much more complex than the example I gave you and when I try to display it, it gives me a blank space.

Is there anyone who knows how to overcome this problem? Thanks.

Here is the GET method I have used:

```
@bp.route('/load_results', methods=['GET'])
def load():
    f = codecs.open("./file.html", 'r', 'utf-8')
    return f.read()
```

Comment: What is the HTML output for the image? Does it have the correct `src`?

Comment: Yes it have the correct src, I have tried to replace the code of the file with the described example and it works. I don't really understand the first question but the HTML file I try to open is a 3D picture plotted in python with the plotly library

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully overcome this problem by modifying my GET method to open the file inside my API like this :

```
import webbrowser

@bp.route('/load_html_picture_file', methods=['GET'])
def load():
    webbrowser.open(path_to_file)
```

Therefore it open my image in a new tab in my webbrowser.
Thanks anyway.